# Running IDW, but values are '<1' not 0.934 so they are Strings not Doubles

Tags: interpolation, string, inverse-distance-weighted, double

I am trying to use some interpolation tools for analytical data of concentrations of Benzene for monitoring wells. A decent amount of our values for Benzene are '<1' (not 0.943 or 0.345) because of how our sampling works here. Therefore, when I convert my excel tables to points, it classifies my Benzene column as a string and I can't use it as the Z value field. Is there anything I can do so I can still accurately run IDW (or a different interpolation tool) using my Benzene concentrations?

Comment: You need to clean up your data prior to loading it into QGIS. I would do this either by removing the data points by giving them a specific value (either something negative (e.g. -9999) and set QGIS to remove them when running your IDW or an amouint agreed upon for describing a trace amount (e.g. 0.5) ). The application needs to know how you want to treat these values and will only work with real numbers.

Comment: I figured that was the only way I'd be able to do it. Just trying to figure out the most accurate way to go about it. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Glad to be of help! I'll post my comment as an answer below so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean up your data prior to loading it into QGIS. I would do this either by removing the data points by giving them a specific value (either something negative (e.g. `-9999`) and set QGIS to remove them when running your IDW or an amouint agreed upon for describing a trace amount (e.g. `0.5`)).

QGIS needs to know how you want to treat these values and it will only work with real numbers.